# How do I add a class in to a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, class, jpanel

This is the JPanel

```
public class DisplayBoard {

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //The main panel
    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    main.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,800) );
    main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //The title panel
    JPanel title = new JPanel();
    title.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 120));
    title.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    JLabel test1 = new JLabel("Title goes here");
    title.add(test1);

    //The side bar panel
    JPanel sidebar = new JPanel();
    sidebar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 800));
    sidebar.add(AddSubtract);
    sidebar.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    JLabel test2 = new JLabel("Sidebar goes here");
    sidebar.add(test2);

    //The panel that displays all the cards
    JPanel cardBoard = new JPanel();
    cardBoard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,640) );

    //adding panels to the main panel
    main.add(cardBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    main.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    main.add(sidebar, BorderLayout.WEST);

    frame.setContentPane(main);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

and I want to add this class into the sidebar panel

```
public class AddSubtract {

int Number = 0;
private JFrame Frame = new JFrame("Math");
private JPanel ContentPane = new JPanel();
private JButton Button1 = new JButton("Add");
private JButton Button2 = new JButton("Subtract");
private JLabel Num = new JLabel ("Number: " + Integer.toString (Number));

public AddSubtract() {

    Frame.setContentPane(ContentPane);
    ContentPane.add(Button1);
    ContentPane.add(Button2);
    ContentPane.add(Num);
    Button1.addActionListener(new Adding());
    Button2.addActionListener(new Subtracting());
}

public class Adding implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Number++;
        Num.setText ("Number: " + Integer.toString (Number));
    }
}

public class Subtracting implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Number--;
        Num.setText ("Number: " + Integer.toString (Number));
    }
}

public void launchFrame(){
    Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Frame.pack();
    Frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    AddSubtract Test = new AddSubtract();
    Test.launchFrame();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me how I can do this ?
I have a feeling that this is not going to work, but I really want to learn the way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Adding a class"?

Comment: I want the class "AddSubtract"
To display in the sidebar panel.

Comment: class `AddSubtract` should `extend JPanel`. Then you add the `JPanel` in the main class

Answer (score 2):

This definately is not going to work. For starters, you have two `main()` methods. Second, if you want to add a class to your Frame, it should extend from `JComponent`. Basically, your code should look like this:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        this.add(new MainPanel())
        //insert all settings here.
    }
}

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    public MainPanel() {
        this.add(new AddSubtract());
        this.add(/*more panels*/)
    }
}

public class AddSubtract extends JPanel {
    public AddSubtract() {
        //add buttons and stuff here
    }
}
```

and variables do NOT start with capitals.

Edit: And when you have some JFrame, it's usually best to have a `main()` method with just one line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainFrame();
}
```

just set the settings and configuration of the `JFrame` in the constructor.

Comment: Or one [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).